# CSS table row border not showing correctly in chrome and IE

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

I have created a simple table with bottom row borders. In Firefox it works perfectly, and borders are being shown in the whole row, but in Chrome and IE 10 it shows only on part of the row :

```
<div style="display:table; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%">
<div style="display:table-row; border-bottom: 1px solid black;"> 
    <div style="display:table-cell;">a </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; width: 15%;">b </div>
</div>
<div style="display:table-row; border-bottom: 1px solid black;"> 
    <div style="display:table-cell; width: 15%;">a </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; width: 15%;">c </div>
</div>
<div style="display:table-row; border-bottom: 1px solid black;"> 
    <div style="display:table-cell;">a </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; width: 15%;">b </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; width: 15%;">c </div>
</div>

</div>
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/vnpnhu33/)

Maybe someone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: (A) in-line styling is horrible (B) You haven't actually said whats wrong/desired clearly and (C) I believe it to be working exactly as it should be?

Comment: I have said that borders are not showed to whole row, it is being showed only to part of the row.

Comment: I don't see a table at all! I see a div doing exactly as it should be, given the properties you have given it. If you want a 'bottom border', why don't you just add a hr tag?

Comment: What you are trying to do is to emulate table cell collspan. Unlikely you will succeed, though. It's much simpler to use normal table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add empty `div`s.

```html
<div style="display:table; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%">
  <div style="display:table-row; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
    <div style="display:table-cell;">a</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; width: 15%;">b</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; width: 15%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="display:table-row; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
    <div style="display:table-cell; width: 15%;">a</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; width: 15%;">c</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; width: 15%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="display:table-row; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
    <div style="display:table-cell;">a</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; width: 15%;">b</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; width: 15%;">c</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Note:** Haven't tested on IE.